# showing http://mysite/page instead of http://mysite/page.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, clean-urls

i want to make a website with my own CMS but i got a problem with pretty urls. i want users to see http://mysite/page instead if seeing http://mysite/page.php . It is somehow like wordpress custom template. thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: These sites might be of some help : http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls--net-6049 and https://code.google.com/p/prettyurls/

Answer (score 5):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```